# Monitoring events in optaplanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have just used optaplanner to develop a typesetting system for nurses. I want to set up a monitoring event to monitor the best results in real time. I want to know where to put the following code.

```
solver.addEventListener(new SolverEventListener<Solution>() {
    @Override
    public void bestSolutionChanged(BestSolutionChangedEvent<Solution> event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
});
```

Comment: After calling `solverFactory.createSolver()`?

Comment: I want to produce the result XML file in real time.                                                   
              protected Solver<Solution_> createSolver() {
        SolverFactory<Solution_> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(solverConfig);
        return solverFactory.buildSolver();
    }